# Formulário de contato e newsletter Ideal

Tags: api, email, formulário, newsletter

Gostaria muito de saber qual seria o framework/api ideal para lidar com formulários de contato e newsletter em uma página simples com informações sobre o serviços de uma empresa. Existe um campo para assinar a newsletter e um formulário de contato. Por ser html estático, procuro uma solução ideal para evitar dependência de um backend em [php](/questions/tagged/php) ou algo do tipo. Uma [api](/questions/tagged/api) seria ideal.

Gostaria de algo simples onde seria possível fazer a lógica client side mesmo. Pensei no [mailchimp](/questions/tagged/mailchimp), mas não sei se ele seria o ideal para o formulário de contato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um **solução extremamente simples**, que até mesmo uma pessoa leiga pode implementar é usar um **[Formulário do Google](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=pt-BR)**. Um formulário do Google pode receber e-mail e outras informações, salvar em uma planilha, e esta então poder ser importada por qualquer serviço de envio de newsletter.

### Vantagens do Formulário do Google (sem envolver programação)

- Simples de implementar
- Rápido de implementar
- Flexível na criação de campos novos
- Exportação fácil
- Não exige conhecimento prévio de programação
- Gratuito

### Desvantagens do Formulário do Google (sem envolver programação)

- Não é possível fazer uma integração perfeita com HTML de sua página sem que a pessoa saiba que está usando Google Forms

### Usar Google Forms com auxílio de API

As limitações do Google Forms sem envolver programação podem ser resolvidas acessando a API de forma direta. Veja [referencia para Google Spreadsheets API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

---

### Adição após edição da pergunta

Agora que você mudou radicalmente sua pergunta, e fazendo a resposta acima ser inútil, o melhor que pode fazer é ler a API direto do Mailchimp em http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/ e tentar fazer via REST com javascript puro.

Se somente isso não for suficiente, porque eu simplesmente não sei se é realmente possível uma solução da forma como você quer, você vai acabar sendo mais simples fazer pelo menos uma chamada no seu próprio servidor, e essa chamada é que acessa APIs dos provedores de newsletter. Ou seja, sua landing page até poderia ser em HTML puro e Javascript básico, mas em algum lugar, no seu próprio servidor, ou em um servidor que intermediaria vários sites, você teria que desenvolver algo em alguma linguagem backend.

**Vale lembrar que provedores de envio de e-mail em massa possivelmente não facilitem muito para criar um modo fácil de enviar por HTML porque isso permitiria muito SPAM**. E ao fornecer uma API simples para fazer em HTML direto, as pessoas iriam reclamar de features mais avançadas, sendo que o MailChimp não foi feito para esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Realmente é útil, mas vou editar a pergunta pois a landing page não é minha e nesse caso é uma página simples com informações sobre o serviço do cliente. E o problema que precisa ter um gerenciamento melhor dos usuários cadastrados na newsletter.

Comment: "a landing page não é minha"... você não tem acesso de escrita ao arquivo? As chamadas de action desses forms estão em locais que você pode editar?

Comment: sim, tenho acesso. O que não tenho é opção de escolher algo como o google forms. Posso utilizar algo como o mailgun e mailchimp.

Comment: @CassioCabral você tem dois problemas, eu dei uma solução mais próxima de envolver o mínimo de trabalho possível para resolver seu problema. Sem envolver o mínimo de desenvolvimento backend, ou fazer seu próprio Webservice para receber a chamada de um ou mais sites que tem essas landing pages (algo que também é uma solução plausível para seu problema) não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: Entendi, realmente eu não tenho problema em usar uma linguagem no backend. É mais por questão de não ter que depender sempre disso e poder aproveitar o uso de APIs.